# Setting "default" metadata for all+new objects in a GCS bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I run a static website (blog) on Google Cloud Storage.

I need to set a default [metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#cache-control) header for `cache-control` header for all existing **and future** objects.

However, [editing object metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#edit) instructions show the [gsutil setmeta -h "cache-control: ..."](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/setmeta) command, which doesn't seem to be neither applying to "future" objects in the bucket, nor giving me a way to set a 
bucket-wide policy that can be inherited to existing/future objects (since the command is executed [per-object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#edit)).

This is surprising to me because there are features like `gsutil defacl`which let you set a policy for the bucket that is inherited by objects created in the future.

Q: Is there a metadata policy for the entire bucket that would apply to all existing and future objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to set default metadata on GCS objects. You have to set the metadata at write time, or you can update it later (e.g., using gsutil setmeta).

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58111385/set-default-meta-data-for-all-future-uploaded-objects-in-gcp-bucket)

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#caching_data), if an object does not have a `Cache-Control` entry, the default value when serving that object would be `public,max-age=3600` if the object is publicly readable.

In the case that you still want to modify this meta-data, you could do that using the [JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#set-object-metadata-json) inside a [Cloud Funtion](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-python) that would be [triggered](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#object_finalize) every time a new object is created or an existing one is overwritten.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help (or, it helps to realize there's a missing feature). It looks like we can't customize the default metadata value on future objects.